# Name of Weekday of given date-time-string

Tags: php, string, datetime

```
$dateTime = '2011-10-25 14:08:32';
```

I would like to display what day `$dateTime` is in PHP. For example. 2011-10-25 is Tuesday.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use PHP's [date()](http://il2.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function

```php
date("l", strtotime($datetime));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$day = date("l", strtotime($dateTime));
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternately, you can use [strftime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php):

```
$day = strftime("%A", strtotime($dateTime));
```

The strftime() in PHP function is equivalent to the function of the same name in C, Perl, GAWK, SQLite, etc.